# I can not connect to the internet

Tags: networking, drivers, internet

I have installed ubuntu on two different computers. In both cases it tells me it needs to download the drivers for the network card, but can not conect to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to find a script version of the driver installer (a .run file for example) if it exists, and then execute it on your computer.

You can also find the source and build them on your system with make and configure.